# Make browser cache form data when submitting with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a web application with a number of forms throughout. Everything is submitted with AJAX rather than doing an actual form submit. The problem I've run into is that I want the browser to still cache the values the user enters in the forms for auto-completion when filling out the same forms later. I'm sure there's something that could be hacked up with localstorage, but I would prefer to use the browser's native caching of form data if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a feature request should be submitted for this purpose.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't know where to submit it. This sounds like something that should be part of the HTML5 spec, but how do you submit a feature request for that?

Comment: Its not caching, you basically want to exploit the browser's auto fill request.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, it completely depends on the settings of the user's browser and cannot be changed. The only way to do it is to use the localStorage (or server-side storage for older browsers).

Comment: Obviously the user has to have form caching enabled, but this is default in firefox and chrome. The problem is that the form is never actually submitted (through conventional means) so the browser never caches it. I've considered doing a fake submit to nowhere, just to make it cache, but I don't like that idea very much.